# How to calculate two input fields and have the total display within an Input Element

Tags: javascript, calculated-field

I'm trying to multiply two input fields and have the result display within the total input element. Can someone tell me where is my problem within this code:

```js
var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
var amount = parseInt(amount, 10);
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
var quantity = parseInt(quantity, 10);
var total = amount * quantity;
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
```

```html
Amount: <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount">
<br> Quantity: <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity">
<br> Total: <input type="number" id="total" name="total">
```

Comment: I think you need to bind a specific event in order to trigger that calculation.

Comment: First, you are re-declaring `amount` and `quantity`. Second--and I think this is the lesser problem--you are setting the "inner HTML" of an `<input>` element to `total` instead of changing its `value` attribute value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById("total").value` instead of `document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total`. Also, you need to trigger your code on a particular event. Here I have just set it up to trigger when the user enters a value into either input field using the `oninput="calc()"` attribute on both your input fields:

```js
function calc() {
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var amount = parseInt(amount, 10);
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  var quantity = parseInt(quantity, 10);
  var total = amount * quantity;
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}
```

```html
Amount: <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" oninput="calc();">
<br> Quantity: <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" oninput="calc();">
<br> Total: <input type="number" id="total" name="total">
```

Comment: This is the functionality I was looking for. Works great! Thanks for all your help. I thought that I needed to execute the calculation in response to an event. Thanks a million!

Comment: the oninput event is new to me. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @Mark Yeah, it’s pretty useful. It can detect changes in both typed input changes and also when the user presses the button to increment/decrement the number :)

Comment: Thanks! I should definitely be using this event on my projects.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to bind an event either to a button (click) or to the input elements (input)

In this example, a button triggers the calculation.

**Here the following adjustments:**

1. Use the attribute `.value` for input-form elements.
2. Use the object `Number` or plus `+` sign to convert to a number.
3. Validates the entered values (this is up to you).

```js
document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var amount = +amount;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  var quantity = +quantity;
  var total = amount * quantity;
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
});
```

```html
Amount: <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount">
<br> Quantity: <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity">
<br>
<br> <input id='calculate' type='button' value='Calculate'>
<br>
<br> Total: <input type="number" id="total" name="total">
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add a function, and call it on input change 
so try to use `oninput` event
and change `document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;` to be `document.getElementById("total").value = total;`

```html
<html><head></head><body>
Amount: <input type="number" oninput="calculate()" id="amount" name="amount">
<br>
Quantity: <input type="number" oninput="calculate()" id="quantity" name="quantity">
<br>
Total: <input type="number" id="total" name="total">

    
 <script>
  function calculate(){
   var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
   var amount = parseInt(amount, 10);
   var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
   var quantity = parseInt(quantity, 10);
   var total = amount * quantity;
   document.getElementById("total").value = total;
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 function compute() {
        var p = document.getElementById("principal").value;
        var r = document.getElementById("rate").value;
        var t = document.getElementById("time").value;
        var answer = (p * r * t) / 100;
        document.getElementById("answer").value = answer;
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me only because I added ".value" at the end of each variable, thus helping the input fields recognize the numbers. Without the ".value" at the end of each variable (p,r and t), the last input field (with the ID: "answer", would display NaN. I hope this helps.